# Sharelatex CVPR ruler

Tags: two-column, templates, sharelatex

I am using sharelatex (great tool) but I haven't been able to find a way to show the ruler (blue numbers on the sides of the paper) that comes with the CVPR template. I was wondering if someone has had the same problem and how did they solve it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, I have *no* idea what CVPR is.

Answer (score 2):

The [CVPR template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/5372a0c2196e12e838a758cd) provides `egpaper_final.tex` and `egpaper_for_review.tex`. The main difference between the two is that the latter (review) version activates the condition `\cvprfinalcopy` (which sets `\cvprfinaltrue`).

Setting `\cvprfinalfalse` (the default) in your preamble (or commenting out `\cvprfinalcopy`) will insert the "blue numbers on the sides of the paper".